# What UIView setter does @synthesize create

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, setter, synthesizer

How to make custom UIView setter. For example:

1) We create property:

```
@property (retain) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel
```

2) we make setter (the same as @synthesize would create):

```
- (void)setMyLabel:(UILabel *)anObject
{
     [myLabel release];
     myLabel = [anObject retain]; 
}
```

Is it correct, or should I check if the new view are not the same as the current with

```
- (void)setMyLabel:(UILabel *)anObject
{
    if(anObject != myView){
        [myLabel release];
        myLabel = [anObject retain]; 
    }
}
```

Just myView and anObject are object pointers. So should we check them with -isEqual method then? Or we don't need to check it at all? What code does @synthesize generates by defaults?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Only the second version (with the `if` statement) is correct. In your first version, imagine that `anObject` and `myLabel` actually point to the same object (i.e., the pointers are the same). In that case, you would release the object, which would cause it to be deallocated if no other object had retained it. The subsequent attempt to retain the deallocated object would cause a crash.

Comment: Ole is right. In addition, you shouldn't check the pointers with "isEqual", since you're trying to see if they point to the same object (not if they point to "equal" objects).

Comment: I prefer the second as well, but it's worth pointing out that you can fix the first by changing the `release` call to `autorelease`.